# How to do modulo calculation?

Tags: math

I'm following an online course and in one of the lecture it is said that add the first number with the second number modulo of 26.

I don't have the foggiest idea how to do it.

assume the first number 25 and the second number is 5. so how to add them along with modulo of 26 !!!

Comment: Hm... did you check the wikipedia article on modular arithmetic? Also, this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modulo arithemtic means that you should use corresponding *remainder*, not the *value itself*. 
In your case:

```
  5 + 25 (mod 26) == 30 % 26 == 4 // <- "%" is taking remainder after dividing on 26
```

Whatever operation you do in mod 26, the answer will be in 0..25 range.

Sample code (C#):

```
  int x = 5;
  int y = 25;
  int mod = 26;
  int result = (x + y) % mod;
```